# How to rotate a flash animation in the z axis

Tags: flash, papervision3d, carousel

THere are 3d carousels in Web Sites for displaying image galleries which require that images are rotated in the z axis. My requirement is to do the same but for a complete flash animation so that the flash animation is displayed slightly tilted in the z-axis
The kind of tilt I am talking about is similar to the tilted images in http://www.flashcomponents.net/component/majestic_3d_cover_flow_xml_horizontal.html

My requirement is to play a flash animation inside the image of a mobile phone which is tilted hence to fit the animation inside the screen of the mobile phone image, the animation also needs to be tilted

Answer (score 0):

In AS3 with Flash Player 10(>=) you can use the rotationX, rotationY and rotationZ properties of the DisplayObjects.

Rob

Comment: What I understand is that I can rotate the images of a particular frame only, so if I have thousands of frames it will extremely time consuming. Is there a way to rotate the whole animation for all the layers in one shot.

Comment: Hi,

If you want to do the rotation on every frame you can use the 3D Rotation Tool in the Flash CS5 IDE. The older versions of Flash can't do it as this tool was introduces in CS5. Also if you want to use the Z and Y axis rotation you must export your Flash file to version 10.0 or higher. Hope it helps. Rob

Comment: Do you mean to say that in CS5 the whole animation can be rotated in one shot without doing it individually in each frame

Comment: No, you can rotate the container movieclip or the shapes individually frame by frame.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve what I wanted that is rotate a complete animation along the z axis by importing the swf file into library of a new Flash file. Then I dragged the movie (imported swf ) onto the stage, created the movie clip and then used the 3d rotation tool. This way the transformation of rotation got applied on the complete animation

Answer (score 0):

To rotate your entire flash file without modifying any keyframes (FLASH - CS6):

1 - Select all your layers and keyframes (<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>" on MAC, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> for those using PC)

2- In the Timeline window at the bottom, select "Edit Multiple Frames" (beside the "Onion Skin Outlines" button). A dark bracket enclosure thingy will appear where your timeline number thingys are.

3- Drag the dark bracket thingy until it spans the length of your animation in the timeline

4- Select the "Free Transform Tool"... then rotate to your desired angle (by placing your mouse pointer to the corner of the current selection)

5- If you need to modify your document width &/or height, go to "Modify - Document" in your top menu

6- Select the "Free Transform Tool" again to deselect

7- Have a donut